# Centura Column locking Technique

Tags: centura

How to implement child table column locking in centura ? 
It is used for providing  better clarity to table windows, having large number of columns locking the key column.Locked columns do not scroll horizontally, they are fixed to the left side of the table window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implementation code snippet:**

Set nColumnID  = SalTblQueryColumnID( tablename.columnname )
Call SalTblSetLockedColumns( Tablename, nColumnID )